# Invalid column name 'deletebatchsize_xact' and 'deletebatchsize_cmd'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

In a sudden my SQL Replication job not synchronizing data but in the history it says all are successful.

After a details check, I'm getting below message from replication properties and from 'View Synchronization Status' window.

The error message is

> Invalid column name 'deletebatchsize_xact'.
>
> Invalid column name 'deletebatchsize_cmd'.
>
> The Distributor has not been installed correctly. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution for the above issue. I added above columns to the system tabled named dbo.MSdistributiondbs

Steps I followed

1. Added new cols in MSDB database and table named dbo.MSdistributiondbs
2. Col names and type deletebatchsize_xact (int), deletebatchsize_cmd (int)
3. Then reprocessed the replication.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, the error happended because I had added a column to a table existing in the publication but I had not added an according column to the subscriber.